# How to find out IDs or names of preloaded system drawables (bitmaps) from memory dump

Tags: android, memory-management, bitmap, android-resources, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I'm analyzing memory usage of our app, and has found strange `Drawables`, which constantly "eats" few megabytes of heap. Here are few screenshots from [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/):

[image: Dominator tree]
*Dominator tree with 2 pretty big bitmaps*

[image: path_to_gc_roots]
*Path to GC roots for one of above bitmaps*

This bitmaps always appears in heap dumps from my phone (*Samsung Galaxy Nexus, OS 4.1.1*), no matter how long or how intensive I use our app.

I've already tried to search the source of this bitmaps using MAT - with no luck. All usefull information I was able to find was`width` and `height` of bitmaps, it's both 512x512:
[image: bitmap_info]

But our app doesn't have any single 512x512 drawables. I assume this is some "system" drawables. But what exactly? Why them so big?

I've also looked at source code of `android.content.res.Resources` class, searching usage of `sPreloadedDrawables` field - also with no luck. All I get from memory dump - is `key` from `sPreloadedDrawables` array, but I can't determine filename or resource id from this key.

So, my questions is:

- **how can I determine names or IDs of this bitmaps**?
- **what for this huge bitmaps are loaded and why they always stays in memory**?

**Update**:

I have found a way to [look at this bitmaps from memory dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709603/mat-eclipse-memory-analyzer-how-to-view-bitmaps-from-memory-dump). This two bitmaps is a simple gradients, one black, other - white. I suppose this is resources for `Holo.Light` and `Holo.Dark` ICS themes. But my second question is still actual: why this bitmaps are always stays in memory? Is there any way to upload or recycle them?

Comment: why do you want the name/id of these bitmaps?

Comment: I want name/id of this bitmaps for trying to figure out what for this bitmaps are loaded and maybe trying to do something with them from my code

Answer (score 0):

This picture from android.jar, which you have to include into your project. There are two squares with the vertical gradient. The first  - from 0x000000 to 0x272d33, the second - from 0xe8e8e8 to 0xfafafa.
You can find them in android.jar/res/drawable-nodpi/background_holo_dark.png and background_holo_light.png. Of course, you can get different results depending on your Android SDK version.

Comment: this didn't answer my question - **how** to find names of this bitmaps having only memory dump? How do you found this names?

Comment: if the resource is public, the then id IS the file name. it should be android.R.drawable.background_holo_[dark|light]

Answer (score 0):

I would guess they stay in memory because they are the default backgrounds for activities. Try specifying a different background in your theme and see if they are still there.

Comment: If this is a case, why there are two themes in memory at a sime time? (dark and light themes)

Answer (score 0):

The preloaded drawables are loaded by Zygote.

`ZygoteInit#preloadResources()`

```
    /**
 * Load in commonly used resources, so they can be shared across
 * processes.
 *
 * These tend to be a few Kbytes, but are frequently in the 20-40K
 * range, and occasionally even larger.
 */
private static void preloadResources() {
    final VMRuntime runtime = VMRuntime.getRuntime();

    try {
        mResources = Resources.getSystem();
        mResources.startPreloading();
        if (PRELOAD_RESOURCES) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Preloading resources...");

            long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            TypedArray ar = mResources.obtainTypedArray(
                    com.android.internal.R.array.preloaded_drawables);
            int N = preloadDrawables(runtime, ar);
            ar.recycle();
            Log.i(TAG, "...preloaded " + N + " resources in "
                    + (SystemClock.uptimeMillis()-startTime) + "ms.");


            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            ar = mResources.obtainTypedArray(
                    com.android.internal.R.array.preloaded_color_state_lists);
            N = preloadColorStateLists(runtime, ar);
            ar.recycle();
            Log.i(TAG, "...preloaded " + N + " resources in "
                    + (SystemClock.uptimeMillis()-startTime) + "ms.");
        }
        mResources.finishPreloading();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Failure preloading resources", e);
    }
}
```

You see, the preloaded drawables are `com.android.internal.R.array.preloaded_drawables`