# MAT (Eclipse Memory Analyzer) - how to get bitmap dimensions from heap dump

Tags: android, memory, analyzer, mat

I'm trying to recreate an image from a heap dump but to do that I must know the dimension of the bitmap in question. I loaded the hprof into MAT but couldn't find a way for it to show the details of the bitmap like the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674484). 
I'd like to get the results like the 3rd image. How can I do that?

**Edited:**
I can only get to the object list:
[The object list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkSsc.png)

**Solution:**As I can't post my own answer yet :)

Remember to open the hprof in the memory analyzer perspective. It may sound stupid but eclipse didn't open mine in it. Once in the memory analyzer perspective, click on the bitmap object, it should list the attributes of the object in the attributes tab.

Comment: Can't you locate the Bitmap object that byte array belongs to?

Comment: Please see the updated question, sorry I can't post images yet.

Comment: if you click to the Bitmap, you should see its attributes.

Comment: hmm, maybe I'm missing something. Where can you get the attributes? I must be short of a window->show view or something

Comment: ok, my bad, I was viewing in debug and java perspective. I didn't notice there was a memory analysis perspective. Problem solved. Thanks auselen for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You can either remove or answer your own question then.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Window > ShowView > Other.. > Inspector
2. Select your android.graphics.Bitmap
3. look at Inspector window :)

for more detail
[MAT (Eclipse Memory Analyzer) - how to view bitmaps from memory dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709603/mat-eclipse-memory-analyzer-how-to-view-bitmaps-from-memory-dump/12709604#12709604)